# Check a disabled radio button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, radio-button

I´m using JQUery Mobile 1.3.1 to check a disabled radio button (i.e. a radio button that cannot be clicked). Unfortunately, my method is not able to check the radio button a disabled radio button. I already tried to find answers here but haven´t found anything useful yet. This is my code:

```
<a href="#" id="activateRadio" data-role="button">Activate radio button flug!</a>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" disabled />
```

and the JQuery mobile function:

```
$('#activateRadio').click(function(){         
      //check if radio button is  not checked

      if ( ! $("input[name='radio3']").is(':checked') ) {
        alert("The button was not checked. Now it should be checked!"); 
        //remove disabled attribute
        $("input[name='radio3']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("input[name='radio3']").attr('checked', 'checked');
      }

      else {
        alert("The button is already checked!");
      }
});
```

Another question would also be how to change the background color of a input field radio when the the radio is checked. How does this look like in the CSS?

Comment: `$("input[name='radio3']").prop('checked', true );`

Answer (score 0):

use `prop()` to change the property..attr just chnages the attributes

```
  if ( ! $("input[name='radio3']").is(':checked') ) {
    alert("The button was not checked. Now it should be checked!"); 
    //remove disabled attribute
    $("input[name='radio3']").prop('disabled',false);
    $("input[name='radio3']").prop('checked', true);

    //or 
    $("input[name='radio3']").prop({'disabled':false',checked':true});

  }

  else {
    alert("The button is already checked!");
  }
```

and not sure if it is radio3 or radio1 since i cannot find radio3 here